# Laravel 5.4 and Mongodb 3.2 Configuration Issue

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

[image]

we are facing isssue in configuring Laravel 5.4 with Mongodb 3.2. We have done follow things but still we are facing issue in this project, it would be great if i will get solution for this

Installed Composer & Install Laravel 5.4

Install Package `composer require mongodb/mongodb` and `composer require jenssegers/mongodb ^3.2`.

we have also add mongodb in our php7.1 (http://mazau.com/info.php)

Default database driver to : mongodb (database.php and .env file)

We have also provide proper database credentials and user details.

We are not facing issue in any of above issue at present. But when we try to execute `php artisan migrate` we face below error.

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class ‘PDO’
>   not found

can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: And do you have PHP PDO extension installed and enabled ? You can check with the `phpinfo();`

Comment: Yes you have to check `phpinfo();` to check PDO extension status.

Comment: @teeyo we have done it please check (http://mazau.com/info.php) we have already done this.

Comment: Our Hosting server has CentOS 7 Installed. FYI.

Comment: And I can't see PDO support, I found PDO only in the credit section ! are you sure PDO is installed ?

Comment: as per my knowledge PDO is for relational database only. while mongodb is uses their own driver. If i am wrong can you please provide link or support so i can download PDO for Mongodb.